# Riemann–Stieltjes integral in Apostol: is the integrating function monotone?

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-integration, stieltjes-integral

By defining the Riemann–Stieltjes integral, Apostol in Mathematical analysis (1974), require for the integrand and integrator to be bounded on the definition interval, but I do not see anywhere that he requires that the integrator (integrating function) be monotone.

Practically everywhere else where a looked, this assumption is given.
Proves are in general easier with monotonicity.

> 1. I'm correct that Apostol does not require monotonicity?
> 2. What are the consequences if we introduce monotonicity? Do we lose a lot?

Comment: Yes the definition in Apostol is more general and requires only bounded integrators.

Comment: The formula for integration by parts deals with $\int f\, dg$ as well as $\int g\, df$. Restricting to monotone integrators makes this result applicable only to the case when both $f, g$ are monotone. The result however holds if one function is continuous and other monotone.

Comment: Also the main advantage of monotone integrators is that we can use Darboux sums in a manner similar to that used in definition of Riemann integral. In other cases (where integrator is not monotone) the Darboux sum approach does not help.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Thank you

Comment: @ParamanandSingh  Is there are other advantage with monotonic integrator?

Comment: @MeetPatel: I am not aware of any other advantage.